# Real time update without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I would like to know the solution on how to make my PHP webpage/table update itself automatically in real time without having to refresh the page. The page works perfectly fine.

For example, If a user submits data this page will update itself automatically displaying the new users data. I have made research and it involves ajax. I have tried some attempts but it messes up the page. Any assistance would be kindly appreciated.

```
 <html>
<head>
 <title>Seminar Overview</title>
 </head>
  <h1><center>Seminar Overview</center>
    <body background="cloud.png">

 <h4><p><a href="add.php">Create Seminar</a></p><h4>
    <h4><p><a href="index.php">Admin Login</a></p><h4>
  <center>
   <?php
   //DISABLE ERRORS
      error_reporting(E_ERROR);
         //ESTABLISH DATABASE SERVER CONNECTION
       $con = mysql_connect ("194.81.104.22", "", ""); 
     if (!$con) {
   die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
}
 //MYSQL QUERY & DATABASE SCHEMA
mysql_select_db("db12408543", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Register";
$seminaroverview = mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $data = mysql_query($sql,$con);
 //TABLE
echo "<table border=4 table width=1000>
<tr>
 <th>Student ID</th>
 <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
         <th>Date of Registration</th>
         <th>Email</th>
            <th>Registered Seminar(s)</th>
              </tr>";


    //MYSQL DATA TO BE DISPLAYED THROUGH PHP TABLE
      while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $record['idRegister'] . "</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $record['Name'] . "</td>"; 
         echo "<td>" . $record['Surname'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $record['Telephone'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $record['Address'] . "</td>"; 
             echo "<td>" . $record['Dateofregistration'] . "</td>"; 
             echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>"; 
                   echo "<td>" . $record['SeminarAttended'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                       }
             echo "</table>";

                  mysql_close($con);

                          ?>
                           </center>
                           </body>
                         </html>
```

> Real time attempt

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function() {  // set Interval function to carry out same operation in the time specified
                    $('#main').load('seminar-overview.php #main > *'); // Reloads 'seminar-overview.php' table every 6 seconds as <div> tag is specified and closed after table
            }, 6000);
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: There's no javascript or ajax in this sample.  If you expect people to assist, you will need to provide some examples you have tried

Comment: AngularJS will allow you to utilize SPA's, single-page applications, and doesn't require you to refresh the page for changes.  It is accomplished through "2-way data-binding" via the DOM hierarchy through $digest.

Comment: You can either do [long polling in Ajax](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) or use something like `Node.JS` to do real-time updates

Comment: ^ obviously you'll want to do the Ajax thing unless you want to scrap all your PHP code and start completely over with Node.JS

Comment: @nomistic take a look at the example I have given

Comment: You can use jquery function `$.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] );// this is a short hand ajax function` And You Should Not Use `mysql_*` functions in your PHP Script as they are deprecated.

Comment: @GourabNag has a great point. Please Please don't use the `mysql` class!  It is deprecated for a reason and is insecure.  Look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) if you want to stick to a similar format.  However, I highly recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  I have been using it for about a year now and I think you will find it much easier and more powerful.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment yeah I should change the mysql class, I appreciate your advice. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after you populate your table for the first time you will need to send the form data to another PHP page via an ajax request.  The example js code below (using jQuery) will execute a new PHP page with POST variables from a form named `#updatePage`.  Then it will set the table contents to the pages output.  Here it is:

```
$('#updatePage').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/script.php",
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('table').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        },
    });
});
```

The script.php might look something like this:

```
<?php
$newData = //MySQL functions to get data using POST vars

echo "
    <tr>
        <td>" . $newData . "</td>
    </tr>
";
?>
```

That's the basic idea and you should be able to modify your code to make this work.

Comment: Other than using `ajax` to send a request to another script, can't we use the Jquery function `$.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) it says that `$.post` is "a shorthand Ajax function" and simply sets up the ajax call for you.

Comment: Yes! I use it as it simplifies everything. But I also consider that AJAX provides a lot of functionality!